# WPF multi-thread progress update

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm need to display some form of feedback to the user, while a small process (7-10 seconds) takes place in the background.

I had no issues in the past using separate threads and BackgroundWorkers in Windows Forms, but its proving difficult in WPF.

I have read many articles, in this respect, and how I should be using dispatchers in WPF to start a new thread, etc. However, when I try to use a BackgroundWorker to display a form of waiting image feedback, it simply remains static.

I don't believe that it matters, but it uses mui from FirstFloor (https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui).

I'm trying to use the built-in ProgressRing feature (which works no problems when run within the same thread and there are no other major tasks running in the background.

Adding a BackgroundWorker, brings an exception due to cross thread access of objects, even though many blogs states that BackgroundWorks in WPF are cross thread aware and safe to run.

The following is the closest code that generates what I need.

```
    private async void MyTaskProcess()
    {

        await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                //Update the waiting ring image
                ProgressRing.IsActive = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                ProgressRing.IsActive = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Thrown");
            }
        }));


        await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            try
            {        
                //Run the main MS Excel export function
                Export2Excel();
                ProgressRing.IsActive = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Thrown");
            }
        }));

    }
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to go and read some more - a `Dispatcher` doesn't start a new thread.  On the contrary, it *ensures* the code is executed on the UI thread!  I'd suggest looking at TPL using `Task<T>` and `async/await`.  `BackgroundWorker` is a bit old hat, though still works fine.

Comment: See the [`BackgroundWorker` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: When using the background worker thread, have you tried setting WorkerReportsProgress to true, and calling ReportProgress? When the ProgressChanged event is raised, it is executed on the thread that creates the background worker, so you should have no problems updating the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do this in a modern WPF application is to start a new `Task` in which you do the work; under the covers this will perform the work on a thread pool thread:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(this.DoWork)
```

Now in `DoWork`to report progress you `InvokeAsync` back to the main thread whenever the porgress count changes:

```
void DoWork()
{
    foreach(var item in this.WorkItems)
    {
        // Do something

        // Report Progress
        ++progress
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => this.Progress = progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian,seems like a better option. I will look into it.

Comment: No probs; as Stephen mentioned there might be more fancy ways to report progress, but fundamentally all you need to do is get your progress value back to the main thread and everything uses the dispatcher to do that under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding a BackgroundWorker, brings an exception due to cross thread access of objects, even though many blogs states that BackgroundWorks in WPF are cross thread aware and safe to run.

`BackgroundWorker` works fine with WPF, *as long as* you create and start the BGW on the UI thread. (As a side note, BGW has the same restriction on Windows Forms). As other commenters have noted, the proper way to do progress updates with BGW is using `ReportProgress`, not `Dispatcher`.

However, I'd recommend using the newer `Task.Run` with `IProgress<T>` for progress updates. I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html) that compares/contrasts the old BGW progress updates with the new `IProgress<T>`-based progress updates.

It's difficult to say what your code should look like, since the code you posted doesn't actually *run* anything on a background thread. In particular, if `Export2Excel` must be run on the UI thread, and that's all your work is doing, then there's no point in using BGW or `Task.Run` at all, since nothing can run on the background thread anyway.

Comment: I was trying to access WPF objects across the main UI thread with other functions of the BackgroundWorker, once I realised that, I only accessed the main UI thread via the ProgressChanged, which seems to be a safe cross thread method, and is all good.

Answer (score 0):

you go, to the below link written by me and read carefully.I hope you will definetily solve your problem:

[Threads in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1c8574/threads-in-wpf/)

Comment: I was trying to access objects that form part of the main UI thread and therefore getting exceptions in my code. After reading your post (which is very detailed and well presented), I understood, that I needed to run all my background processing in the DoWork and simply update the user via the ProgressChanged.Thanks again.